# Spring Data Elasticsearch ReactiveElasticsearchTemplate logs a lot of warnings: pit/search_after was cancelled

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-data-elasticsearch

What does this warning mean and how to get rid of it?

```
pit/search_after was cancelled
```

logger: `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ReactiveElasticsearchTemplate`

We have a `spring-data-elasticsearch:jar:5.2.0` with `spring-boot:3.2.0`, but our Elasticsearch still run in some old version: 7.17.8

Might this be a cause?

Answer (score 0):

This is logged when the `Flux` returned by `ReactiveElasticsearchTemplate.search` method is cancelled. You can set the log level of `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ReactiveElasticsearchTemplate` to less than `WARN`, or consume the data from the returned `Flux`.